# segregated witness adoption

Tags: mining-pools, segregated-witness

What happens if segregated witness never reaches the 95% adoption threshold from miners? Will it still take effect for those transactions where the miners have adopted it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This BIP is to be deployed by version-bits BIP9. Exact details TDB."

https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/4cpl1y/segregated_witness_when_and_how_does_it_activate/

As soon as testing is complete final details should be determined. It sounds like a segwit soft fork is possible

There will not be a need to wait for a 95% adoption threshold:

"A main benefit of the current Segregated Witness design is that it can be deployed as a soft fork. Once the code is accepted and merged, only miners will need to upgrade; all other users can change their software if and whenever they want to, with no risk of being thrown off the network."

https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/segregated-witness-enters-final-testnet-stage-includes-lightning-network-support-1459357231

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is incorrect. SegWit will only activate after 95% miner acceptance. There will be a soft fork and it will be backward compatible so users can update in their own time. But it still requires 95%.

Comment: The "only miners need to upgrade" is exactly the 95% threshold specified by BIP9. The fact that it is a softfork just makes it safe for non-miners to not update. It doesn't avoid the need for a 95% threshold.

Answer (score 2):

By current agreement Segregated Witness will only activate after it reaches 95% of the miners signaling readiness.

Sending Segregated Witness transactions before that would be foolish, as if they were to be included in a block, anyone would be able to spend the outputs before Segregated Witness is enforced. They are however, non-standard to current versions of Bitcoin Core.

If the 95% threshold is not achieved for an extended period of time, there might be a proposal to lower the threshold.

Comment: Note that segwit transactions are non-standard to all Bitcoin Core versions since 0.10, so they are unlikely to be mined (but still, don't bet on that).